# must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I need help with problems loading my landing page. I keep getting this messages on my "inspector" in chrome -

> Denying load of chrome-extension://bjgfdlplhmndoonmofmflcbiohgbkifn/js/lib/jquery-2.0.2.min.map. Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.
>
> Denying load of chrome-extension://bjgfdlplhmndoonmofmflcbiohgbkifn/js/lib/backbone-min.map. Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.
>
> GET chrome-extension://invalid/

This is the link for my website  http://www.itayroisman.com

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: The only message I have is: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 410 (Gone) http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json/?callback=jQuery182019…ame=itay101&include_rts=true&count=5&include_entities=true&_=1376288554695" - Are you sure it is not something related to your browser?

Comment: I really don't know. It takes ages for the page to finish loading. Is everything working well on your side?

Comment: For me the page loads instantly

Answer (score 8):

The Hootsuite chrome extension doesn't seem to be compatible with the latest build of chrome. 
Go to tools>extensions and click Developer mode. The id numbers come up on each of your extensions and you can match them to the errors in Developer Tools

Answer (score 3):

I found [another anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20511168/chrome-extension-error-loading-jquery) may be OK.

Just remove this line from the top of jquery file

//@ sourceMappingURL=jquery-1.10.2.min.map
If you check the source of Jquery 1.10.2, it has included source map line on the top. I hope you are not using Source Maps. For more details just check these links:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/
jQuery's jquery-1.10.2.min.map is triggering a 404 (Not Found)
Alternate approach

Download the source map file from jquery downloads page and put jquery-1.10.2.min.map in the extension directory.
Download uncompressed source code as well and put in the extension directory.
Basically you need three files [SourceMap, Compressed, Uncompressed].
Add these map file path and uncompressed file paths to web_accesible resources.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem.

**If you're not using the the sourcemap:**

1. Open your jquery.js, remove the following line fro mthe top of the file:

   `//@ sourceMappingURL=jquery-2.0.3.min.map`

**If you do want the sourcemap:**

1. Download code.jquery.com/yourfilename (see the comment in your jquery file, mentioned above)
2. Add a line line

   `"web_accessible_resources": [
     "js/jquery-2.0.3.min.map"
   ],`

   To your manifest.json
3. Reload your extension.

Comment: Finally the answer about where to enter the value!

Answer (score 1):

For me disabling: XPath Helper 1.0.13 in chrome://extensions/ solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

For those who are developing a Chrome extension and are having this same problem, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18489135/778272) may help you.

Comment: How does this relate to the specific problem?