# Error 'jquery-2.0.2.min.map not found'

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-devtools

I'm getting this error in Google Chrome developer tools:

> jquery-2.0.2.min.map not found

I found a way to get rid of it by removing this line from my `jquery-2.0.2.min.js`:

```
//@ sourceMappingURL=jquery-2.0.2.min.map
```

However, I don't believe this was a good idea, since this may be just a temporary fix that may be a problem in the future. Since I don't really understand the nature of this error and the goofy solution: what's causing this error and is there a better fix for it?

Apparently, this is not a question related to [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) 2.0.2 only. A very similar Stack Overflow question with a great explanation is *[jQuery's jquery-1.10.2.min.map is triggering a 404 (Not Found)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18365315/1479895)*. I hope this will shed some light on the situation.

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365315/jquerys-jquery-1-10-2-min-map-is-triggering-a-404-not-found/

Answer (score 86, accepted):

**1. [Download](http://jquery.com/download/) the map file and uncompressed version of jquery. Put them with minified version.**
[image: JavaScript]

**2. Include minified version into your HTML**
[image: HTML]

**3. Check in Chrome**
[image: Chrome]

**4. Read [Introduction to JavaScript Source Maps](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/)**

**5. Get familiar with [Debugging JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging)**

Answer (score 36):

You should have a file included in your download of jquery-2.0.2 called `jquery-2.0.2.min.map` make sure it is in the same location as `jquery-2.0.2.min.js` and you should be good to go.

If you don't have a copy you can download it here: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.min.map

Some more background about this from the [jQuery website](http://jquery.com/download/).

> Starting with jQuery 1.9, we also make available sourcemap files that
>   can be used to debug the compressed file in sourcemap-aware browsers
>   such as Google Chrome. The map file is not required for users to run
>   jQuery, it just improves the developer's debugger experience.

Answer (score 4):

As it is announced in `jQuery 1.11.0/2.1.0 Beta 2 Released` the source map comment will be removed so the issue will not appear in newer  versions of `jQuery`.

Anyway, if you need to use a source map, it still be available:

> We’ll still be generating and distributing sourcemaps, but you will
>   need to add the appropriate sourcemap comment at the end of the
>   minified file if the browser does not support manually associating map
>   files (currently, none do). If you generate your own jQuery file using
>   the custom build process, the sourcemap comment will be present in the
>   minified file and the map is generated; you can either leave it in and
>   use sourcemaps or edit it out and ignore the map file entirely.

[Here](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/11/15/jquery-1-11-02-1-0-beta-2-released/) you find more details about the changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the 404 by removing the line

```
//@ sourceMappingURL=jquery-2.1.2.min.map
```

from the top part of your jQuery file.

**Purpose of a source map**

Basically it's a way to map a combined/minified file back to an unbuilt state. When you build for production, along with minifying and combining your JavaScript files, you generate a source map which holds information about your original files. When you query a certain line and column number in your generated JavaScript you can do a lookup in the source map which returns the original location.