# copied file not working - id not working across different pages html javascript php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css-selectors

I have a very simple task that just isn't working, and I have no idea why.  I have a PHP file (with mostly HTML in it) that I simply copied to another file in the same folder, expecting to have the same functionality.  I have two buttons that are supposed to popup a window when pressed, but in the new page, whenever a button is pressed, I get the pageURL+ #id of form in the URL, and nothing happens. For example: 
     "{/project/login.php#loginmode}"  //yes, it's on localhost

The way I understand it, id's must be unique within a page, but should they also be unique across pages within a folder?  I tried changing the id names, only to find the new id names showing up in the URL.  I also tried copying the original file to a completely different directory, and still, the same problem.  Then I tried changing the ID names there, and still, no go.  What am I missing??  I have restarted my server and cleared my cache many times...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf=8"/>
    <title>TITLE/title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" me2dia="screen" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">       
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Terminal+Dosis' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.leanModal.min.js"></script>

    <div id = "top">
        <center>
            <nav>
                <a class="navbtn" href="about.php" style="padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px">  ABOUT</a> |
                <a href="#loginmode" class="navbtn modaltrigger" style="padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px">  LOGIN  </a> |
                <a href="#contactmodal" class="navbtn modaltrigger" style="padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px"> CONTACT</a> 
            </nav>
        </center>
        </br></br></br>
    </div> 

    <!--script for checking logging and creating user--> 
    <script type = "text/javascript">  
        function checkLogin(){ 
            var u = document.getElementById("username").value;
            var p = document.getElementById("password").value;

            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) //using AJAX
              {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
              xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();  
              }
            else
              {// code for IE6, IE5
              xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
              }

            //using AJAX:        
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
                    if(xmlhttp.responseText == u){
                        alert('You have entered a correct username and/or password.');
                        window.location = 'home.php'; //should change from home to newposting.php???
                    }
                    else{
                        alert('You have entered an incorrect username/password combination.  Please try again.');
                        //href=\"javascript:history.go(-2)\"
                        //window.location = 'loginredo.php';                    
                    }
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "checkpw.php?u=" + u + "&p=" + p, true);
            xmlhttp.send(); 
        }

        function newUser(){
            location.href = 'signup.php';

        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>  
    <center>
    <!--Login-->
        <div id="loginmode" style="display:none;">
          <logh1>Sign In:</logh1>
          <form id="loginforme" name="loginforme" method="post" action="index.html">
            <label for="username"><h2>Username:</h2></label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="txtfield" tabindex="1">

            <label for="password"><h2>Password:</h2></label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="txtfield" tabindex="2">

            <div class="center">
                <input type="submit" name="loginbtn" id="loginbtn" class="flatbtn-blu hidemodal" value="Log In" onclick="checkLogin(); return false;" tabindex="3">
                <input type="submit" name="newusrbtn" id="create-user"" class="flatbtn-blu hidemodal" value="New User" onclick="newUser();" tabindex="4">
            </div>

          </form>
        </div>

    <!--Contact-->
        <div id="contactmodal" style="display:none;">

          <logh1>Contact GULSEN:</logh1>
          <form name="contactform" action="contact.php" method="post"> <!--cannot have id="contactform"-->
            <label for="cf_first_name"><h2>First Name</h2></label>
            <input type="text" name="cf_first_name" class="txtfield" tabindex="1">

            <label for="cf_last_name"><h2>Last Name</h2></label>
            <input type="text" name="cf_last_name" class="txtfield" tabindex="2">

            <label for="cf_email"><h2>Email Address</h2></label>
            <input type="text" name="cf_email" id="cf_email" class="txtfield" tabindex="3">

            <label for="password"><h2>Message</h2></label>
            <textarea name="cf_message" cols="100" rows="5" class="txtfield" tabindex="4" style="resize: none; outline: none"></textarea>      

            <label for="cf_reference"><h2>How did you hear about GULSEN?</h2></label>
            <input type="text" name="cf_reference" id="cf_reference" class="txtfield" tabindex="5">   

            <div class="center">  
              <input type="submit" class="flatbtn-blu" value="Send">
              <input type="reset" class="flatbtn-blu" value="Clear">
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
    </center>  

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
          $('#loginforme').submit(function(e){
            return false;
          });

        $('#contactform').submit(function(e){
            return false;
          });

          $('.modaltrigger').leanModal({ top: 110, overlay: 0.45, closeButton: ".hidemodal" });

        });
    </script>  

<div id="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you put this in a different folder..?

Comment: Where is the code to catpture the click event ?

Comment: @tymeJV: I initially tried this on a different page in the same folder, and when that didn't work, I tried a completely different folder (copying along with it any necessary files) and that also did not work.

Comment: @Deepak: if by click event code, you're referring to index.html, it does not exist, and for some reason, my original code from my original page still works. (I'm assuming we're only focusing on the Login section.)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code,

```
$(".modaltrigger").click(function(){
  var href= $(this).attr('href');
  $(href).show();
});
```

**EDIT**
But I doubt the `JS` files are not loaded properly. See if you are getting any errors on the console of the browser using `Inspect Element` tool.

Comment: That didn't really work.  The box, did show, but it didn't really popout and blacken the rest of the page behind it like in my original page.  I used the Inspect Element tool, which only told me I was missing some jQuery libraries, which I quickly, copied over, which got rid of those error messages, but ended up with another error message: "GET http://localhost/gulsen/js/jquery.min.map 404 (Not Found)", for which I do not have nor have ever used.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: When it says not found you might have asked your file to include that `jquery.min.map` somewhere. Is it giving you any line number from where the 404 error is poping out ?

Comment: It says the 404 error is on line 1 of my file, which is <!DOCTYPE html> :/  I'm not sure what this means, considering that my other file starts this way too.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487596/jquery-2-0-2-min-map-not-found