# Google Chrome crushes when multiple html5 videos are at the same page - how to prevent?

Tags: html, google-chrome, video, crash

I have one video on my page but I overwrite the attributes and source file links via jQuery when clicking on a thumbnail. It works perfectly in Firefox, but when playing or closing the second video in Chrome there is a browser crash. Anything I could do to work that out? Do I have to erase the browser cache after closing the first video maybe? Any ideas? Anyone with the same problem?

Comment: do you have a sample that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: http://flowcenter4.flowworks.de/psdb/screeningroom/QtLMcUhNvKnDpMwphMUo_layout/8/

Comment: I can see it crashing, but not sure why. Do you have a smaller sample that just had the video load/hide code that also shows the problem?

Comment: no sorry. But I did some research on the internet and chrome just seems to have problems with html5 videos. Probably I'll just have to add another video player...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the jQuery.min.map file was missing. If you have the same problem please have a look at this post: [Error 'jquery-2.0.2.min.map not found'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487596/error-jquery-2-0-2-min-map-not-found)

After downloading and renaming the min map file it worked