# Chrome Extension Error Loading Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I am working on a chrome extension and my content script was throwing an error

> $/jQuery not being defined.

So I tried embedding jquery using my manifest file and I downloaded jquery in my extension folder but for whatever reason I am receiving this error --

> Denying load of
>   **chrome-extension://gfdmfdmhnoenciioooikdifmdkechdbl/jquery-1.10.2.min.map**.
>   Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key
>   in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.

I tried a couple of things with my manifest file but nothing seems to work so now Im trying this and its still giving me the error --

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name":    "My Extension",
    "version": "0.0",
    "offline_enabled": false,

    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches":    ["*://*.sitedomain.com/*"],
        "js": [
                "jquery-1.10.2.min.js", 
                "content.js"
            ],
        "run_at":     "document_end",
        "all_frames": false
    }]
}
```

I am unable to edit the actual site its to be used on so I can't load jquery the old fashion way in the header, thats why Im trying to load with the extension so my content script will work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `jquery-1.10.2.min.map` is in the error but you have mentioned `jquery-1.10.2.min.js` in your content script. Are you sure there is no typo in path of jquery ?

Comment: @blunderboy I have both jquery-1.10.2.min and jquery-1.10.2.min.map in my folder, and I dont see no type. I tried including .map file with web_resources... and still Im receiving the error

Comment: Are you using source map ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery's jquery-1.10.2.min.map is triggering a 404 (Not Found)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365315/jquerys-jquery-1-10-2-min-map-is-triggering-a-404-not-found)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove this line from the top of jquery file

```
//@ sourceMappingURL=jquery-1.10.2.min.map
```

If you check the source of [Jquery 1.10.2](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js), it has included source map line on the top.
I hope you are not using Source Maps. For more details just check these links:

1. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/
2. [jQuery's jquery-1.10.2.min.map is triggering a 404 (Not Found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365315/jquerys-jquery-1-10-2-min-map-is-triggering-a-404-not-found)

### **Alternate approach**

1. Download the source map file from [jquery downloads page](http://jquery.com/download/) and put `jquery-1.10.2.min.map` in the extension directory.
2. Download `uncompressed source code` as well and put in the extension directory.
3. Basically you need three files [SourceMap, Compressed, Uncompressed].
4. Add these map file path and uncompressed file paths to `web_accesible resources`.

Comment: @ExpertSystem I didn't actually try that approach. Yes you are right. I should update the answer as per Konrad's comment. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Ok Im going to have to try the alternate approach cause for some reason I ended up receiving the error again.

Comment: I tried it and mine got away. Did removing of line approach not work at all for you ?

Comment: The latest jquery releases (1.11 & 2.1) no longer include this line, for this reason.

Comment: Thanks @Teepeemm for letting us know.