# Chrome Extension: How to solve "Not allowed to load local resource" error upon content script injection

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I tried to inject jQuery to content page to make easy access to DOM elements.
The code was something like below

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, { file: "jquery.min.js"} ,function(){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, { file: myOwnScript.js});}
);
```

It was all fine on Windows, but on Ubuntu, in content page window, I always get console error message saying
"Not allowed to load local resource: file:///****/jquery.min.map"

I noted it was talking about *.**map** but not *.**js**

There are some more mysteies:
1. There is no error message on *myOwnScript.js*
2. My extension works well even though this message keeps showing at each page load.

I made plenty searches on Google but didn't find similar case.

My questions is,
1. What is the reason of such error?
2. Should I take it as a serious error?

My enviroment is as below
OS  : Ubuntu 14.04, with LXDE desktop
Chrome  : 34.0.1847.132
(Didn't try other configurations because I am not that good at customizing Linux :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery's jquery-1.10.2.min.map is triggering a 404 (Not Found)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365315/jquerys-jquery-1-10-2-min-map-is-triggering-a-404-not-found)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Previous versions of Jquery have a comment pointing to the map file (so that a bug in jquery.min.js can be translated to a bug in the readable jquery.js).  You can safely delete this comment, or upgrade to a more recent version of Jquery, which has removed this comment (for exactly this reason). See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20512016/2336725).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365315/jquerys-jquery-1-10-2-min-map-is-triggering-a-404-not-found

Comment: Thank you guys. A good lesson. I should have focused more on jQuery other than content script security.