# What does this error message mean

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Hi I just want know what this error message means

> Denying load of chrome-extension://cmbbgcooaabknohabmoaikiakkoignai/jquery.min.map. Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.

Comment: There's something wrong with one of your Chrome extensions (id `cmbbgcooaabknohabmoaikiakkoignai`). Find the extension with that unique ID in `chrome://extensions` and google around to see if anyone else has a similar problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome Extension Error Loading Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20511168/chrome-extension-error-loading-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

It means one of your Chrome extensions is using a compressed version of jQuery which contains a `sourceMappingURL` comment, and the extension's developer is most likely unaware of that.

[Source mapping](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/) is used for debugging purposes, failing to load a `map` file won't affect the script's execution.

It is also worth noting that newer versions of jQuery no longer contain the `sourceMappingURL` comment by default. From the [jQuery 1.11 and 2.1 release announcement](http://blog.jquery.com/2014/01/24/jquery-1-11-and-2-1-released/):

> ### Sourcemap changes
>
> This release does not contain the sourcemap comment in the minified
>   file. Sourcemaps have proven to be a very problematic and puzzling
>   thing to developers, spawning [hundreds of confused developers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365315/jquerys-jquery-1-10-2-min-map-is-triggering-a-404-not-found) on
>   forums like StackOverflow and causing some to think jQuery itself was
>   broken.

---

As an user, you can safely ignore that error. The browser will only attempt to load the `map` file when DevTools is opened (and has the "JS source maps" DevTools setting enabled). If it fails to load the `map` file, nothing changes.

As a developer, you can remove that error message by either upgrading to the latest jQuery version, or manually remove the `sourceMappingURL` comment from the compressed file, or, if you want to use source mapping, make the `map` and uncompressed `js` files available. See [this related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18365315/1331430) as well.